# Refactoring structure to accommodate microservices

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to find an appropriate solution for refactoring an existing class structure using inheritance to microservices.

The existing class structure

```
Person
Instructor inherits Person
Participant inherits Person
xyz inherits Person
```

All class can be created(Person is not abstract)
This structure is created to accommodate situations where an new instructor or new participant is an existing Person.

So a Person can be both Instructor and Participant or zyz.

Database structure

```
Person table
Id

Instructor table
Id(same as person)

Participant table
Id(same as person)
```

Selects on Instructor and Participant joins to Person Id

[Here is a bit more of the class structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka5g4.png)
I am planing on creating Course-service with the responsibility of creating Courses and Registrations and an Payment-service that acts on registration Created. And a HR-service that deals with salary for the instructors when the course is marked as finished.

In the registration flow there needs to be a lookup on existing person.
Since a Participant can already exist in the system(either as existing Participant or as an Instructor(not on the same Course) or xyz implementation of person).

Should i create a service for each class and have the services for the subclass be dependent on the person service?
Or would the best option be to create a person-service that can query Instructor-service and Participant-service and returning Person objects(marking Person as abstract or as an interface and removing the option to create persons)?

Comment: Microservices have to do with how you create and package independent modules, NOT how you create the classes they contain or the inheritance relation between them.

Comment: What your talking about is integral workings of a "Service"... That to me sounds like a "UserService"... You don't need a service per type.

Comment: could you elaborate?